# How do you playback MP4 video in a Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm wondering what the best way is to play back an MP4 video in a Windows Forms application (.NET 2.0) on Vista and XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [Embed Windows Media Player on a Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953.aspx).

**UPDATE**: WMP doesn't support MP4 out-of-the-box, but there are [codecs packs](http://www.tech-faq.com/windows-media-player-mp4-codec.shtml) that add such support. It's possible to bundle a codec installation with your setup, but I think WMP is able to fetch and install MP4 codec on its own.

Comment: Windows Media Player does not play MP4 files (it only does on Windows 7)

Comment: I found this codec pack and it works great:

http://www.medialooks.com/products/directshow_filters/quicktime_filter.html

Answer (score 0):

Either embedding media player or look at managed DirectX (although MDX is a bit old now)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at iSpy - it's open source and wraps VLC player for mp4 playback.

http://www.ispyconnect.com