# How to play .mp4 video in winform.net

Tags: .net, winforms, video, mp4

I am new to winform development, my boss want to display some videos stored in the local disk, no buttons are needed, just find all the videos and play the .mp4 videos one by one.

I have done a search on the internet and cannot find a single solution, have tried the DirectShow example and it throw exception while testing on .mp4 files.

Some said I can add the WMP into the form but I cannot find the WMP COM competent on the dev server.

Comment: You can use Windows Media Player control.Right click on a group in toolbox and click `Choose Items` then from `COM Components` tab, select `Windows Media Player` and check it and click `OK`.

Comment: Hi Reza, thanks for your comment, I heard some said your method before but like as I said, I don't have the WMP in the dialog box, I know it should be listed right under the Windows Mail Mime Editor, instead, I got WizCombo Class.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573841/how-do-you-playback-mp4-video-in-a-windows-forms-app) to play video files in .net